# Syncing with and without Sql Server 2008 changes tracking

Tags: sql-server-2008, change-tracking, microsoft-sync-framework

I've stuck with syncing a Sql server 2008 having changes tracking enabled with a 2005 one that doesn't have this mechanism.

Would you please point me a right track, how can I handle this.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [sql server replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) first.

If that is not an option, you can use the sample in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726015.aspx) msdn article as an example of syncing a store with a custom metadata tracking technique (the sql compact db in the article) with a sql 2008 db with change tracking.
If you replace the SqlCeClientSyncProvider with the SqlExpressClientSyncProvider as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1656652/23697) SO article, but still continue to use the custom metadata tracking technique as with the compact db, you should be able to get there.